# how to compare a date with current date in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a validFrom and validTo date field in my domain class in grails project. I want to create a service on the basis of its validation. can anyone pls tell me how to check if it is greater or lesser than current system date?

Answer (score 8):

It's

```
Date now = new Date()
if (validFrom.before(now) && validTo.after(now)) {
  //valid for this moment
}
```

Comment: Groovy also allows dates to be compared with the standard relational operators: e.g. `validFrom < now && validTo > now`

Comment: @ataylor any official reference of that relational operators ? Thanks