# Comparing Date object to date-formatted String in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy, operator-overloading, dsl

I want to be able to directly compare a Date object to a date-formatted String in a Groovy script, like below:

```
if ( today > "01-01-2017" & today < "10-03-2017")
    *do something*
```

For this, I tried to extend Date class to have a compareTo method to String, like:

```
Date.metaClass.compareTo = {String s -> Date other = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", s);  
                            delegate.numberAwareCompareTo(other)}
```

It is giving me

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

If I do

```
Date.metaClass.compareTo << {String s -> Date other = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", s);  
                            delegate.numberAwareCompareTo(other)}
```

then, I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot add new method [compareTo] for arguments [[class java.lang.String]]. It already exists!
```

If it already exists, why can I not compare Date to String? Why doesn't it recognize my overriding of compareTo method? 
Help appreciated. Thanks,

Edit: This question was flagged as duplicate of [how to compare a date with current date in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535965/how-to-compare-a-date-with-current-date-in-groovy). My question is different, because it is about how to compare a Date object to a date-formatted String by operator overloading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare a date with current date in groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535965/how-to-compare-a-date-with-current-date-in-groovy)

Comment: Why do you want to compare a date and a string?  Why not write a short named wrapper function that changes your strings to Dates?

Comment: Or format the date object to a string.

Comment: Also, the logical AND operator is `&&` not `&`

Comment: @tim_yates I am writing a domain-specific language. Domain expert, who might not know coding, will write a script, which, then, will be passed as a string and evaluated. Right now, I am doing exactly as you suggest, so user script is _today > date("01-01-2017")_ . It would be much simpler if they can just write _today > "01-01-2017"_. If this is not possible, I will go with the former way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things a bit... Changing metaclass in a simple script? Why?

How about you parse your string date to a Date and simply use existing Date comparator?

```
Date now = new Date()
String stringDate = "10-03-2017"
Date parsedDate= Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", stringDate)

if(parsedDate > now) {
...
```

For clarification, `>` calls java.util.Date's `compareTo()`, just another Groovy syntactic sugar

Comment: I am writing a domain-specific language. Aim is that a user (possibly not a programmer, but a domain expert) will write a script, which then, will be passed as a String and evaluated. I want the user to be able to write: 'today > "01-01-2017" ' .